# How to render the materail element added using innerHTML in typescript?

Tags: html, typescript, angular5, angular-material2

Adding material design elements using innerHTML attribute renders a result. But if we develop a html page with the same material design content without using innerHTML attribute produces different result.

here is the example

*html file **material design content directly inserted**:*

```
 <div id="requestForm">
   <button mat-raised-button color="primary" id="proceed_btn" style="margin-right: 15px;" (click)="reset()" *ngIf="request_form_selectedIndex > 2">Submit<i class="material-icons right material_icons_btn">send</i>
   </button>
 </div>
```

in the browser's dom the above page rendered like this.
***expected result***

```
<div id="requestForm">
<button _ngcontent-c3="" color="primary" id="proceed_btn" mat-raised-button="" style="margin-right: 15px;" class="mat-raised-button mat-primary ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-color="primary">
  <span class="mat-button-wrapper">Submit
    <i _ngcontent-c3="" class="material-icons right material_icons_btn">send</i>
  </span>
  <div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple="" ng-reflect-centered="false" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]"></div>
  <div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div>
</button>
```

But when I try to insert the material element using *innerHTML* attribute, it does not render the same result.

***html file:***

```
<div id="requestForm">
</div>
```

***ts file:***

```
htmlElement1 = "<button mat-raised-button color=\"primary\" id=\"proceed_btn\" style=\"margin: 95px 15px;\" (click) =\"reset()\" *ngIf=\"request_form_selectedIndex > 2\">Submit <i class=\"material-icons right material_icons_btn\">send</i> </button>"

document.getElementById("requestForm").innerHTML = htmlElement1;
```

in the browser's dom the above page renders the following result.

> but I want the above mentioned expecpted result while adding material
>   element through the innerHTML attribute.

***my result***

```
<div _ngcontent-c3="" id="requestForm">
  <button mat-raised-button="" color="primary" id="proceed_btn" style="margin: 95px 15px;" (click)="reset()" *ngif="request_form_selectedIndex > 2">Submit 
    <i class="material-icons right material_icons_btn">send</i> 
  </button>
</div>
```

what shoud I do to get my expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Angular sanitizes DOM manipulation so that unsafe (potentially hackable) things won't work. The  tag is obvious, but  also won't work as well as others. You haven't said what you are *trying* to achieve, so it's not possible to make a good recommendation other than the obvious - insert DOM from the DOM (like your first example). If you need conditional insertion, use ngIf or ngSwitch.